# react-navigation 5.0 - Drawers on each side of the screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to get drawers from each side of the screen.

However I can't open the one on the right.

I tried to use the openDrawer () method as well as the dangerouslyGetParent () method. OpenDrawer () but nothing works.

Here is the code I wrote :

```
const UserDrawer = createDrawerNavigator()
const UserMenu = () => (
  <UserDrawer.Navigator
    drawerType="slide"
    overlayColor="rgba(49, 70, 111, 0.75)"
    drawerPosition="right"
    >
    <UserDrawer.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile}/>
    <UserDrawer.Screen name="Company" component={Company}/>
  </UserDrawer.Navigator>
)

const DashboardDrawer = createDrawerNavigator()
const DashboardMenu = () => (
  <DashboardDrawer.Navigator
    drawerType="slide"
    overlayColor="rgba(49, 70, 111, 0.75)"
    drawerPosition="left"
    initialRouteName="Dashboard"
    >
    <DashboardDrawer.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
    <DashboardDrawer.Screen name="Enterprise" component={Enterprise}/>
    <DashboardDrawer.Screen name="Cases" component={Cases}/>
    <DashboardDrawer.Screen name="Customers" component={Customers}/>
    <DashboardDrawer.Screen name="Unpaid" component={Unpaid}/>
    <DashboardDrawer.Screen name="Payments" component={Payments}/>
    <DashboardDrawer.Screen name="Recommendations" component={Recommendations}/>
    <DashboardDrawer.Screen name="UserNavigation" component={UserNavigation}/>
  </DashboardDrawer.Navigator>
)

const AppStack = createStackNavigator()
const AppNavigation = () => (
  <AppStack.Navigator headerMode="none">
    <AppStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeNavigation} />
    <AppStack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={DashboardNavigation} />
  </AppStack.Navigator>
)

const AppNavigationContainer = () => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <AppNavigation />
  </NavigationContainer>
)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you provide the code that uses the Drawer? I would expect that it's inside  `HomeNavigation` & `DashboardNavigation`.

Comment: I'm trying to open drawers from icons in the header. https://codeshare.io/5vOjED